# Element wise sum of two fixed length arrays of integers

Tags: c, algorithm, sse

Say i have two fixed length arrays of unsigned integers.
How do i element wise sum those arrays (into first) without looping or with a lesser number loops?

```
uint64_t foo[10] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
uint64_t bar[10] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
... // funky code without loop so that
    // foo now is {0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18}
```

The related question: *is it possible to sum multiple uint64_t integers in one operation?*. (i bet this could be done with sse)

The question in general is: what is the fastest way to sum two fixed length arrays of integer type (in place into first one)?

Comment: You could trust your compiler to vectorise the code automatically...

Comment: if the length of the array is not only fixed, but also known to you, you could just unroll the loop. that being said, I don't really see any harm in a simple loop like that.

Comment: seems like homework and hence the constraint to not use loop :)

Comment: @Vikdor but there's not much else to do. everything fancy you maybe could do using some C magic would just be compiled to a loop, however unrolled. at least on intel architecture.

Comment: Can you clarify your question by saying element wise sum ??

Comment: Exactly why do you want to do that? I mean, when you want to use the sums, you can calculate them one-by-one as you need them, instead of precomputing the whole thing. So for instance when your program needs `sum[i]` (which is the same as `foo[i]` after the *funky code* part), it goes and sums `foo[i] + bar[i]`, instead of looking up an already-computed sum. Just a thought.

Comment: @Abody97 see foo[] is summed a lot of times in tight loop where bar[] changes every iteration. I am just accumulating some numbers. It is not so slow. I am just have general question of how to make it faster, because i was thinking there must be some kind of bitwise magic that for example sum two int [16] in a one processor instruction, or maybe more general algorithm that can take 2 pointers and type _sum_(void * p1, void *p2, sizeof(uint64_t)) and make it efficient.

Comment: If you want to add *many* things to foo it might even be worth putting foo in registers permanently. It would take 5 xmm registers, but it you can spare them it would let you skip two thirds of the memory accesses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `_mm_add_epi64` to add two 64 bit ints per iteration. I wouldn't expect a dramatic improvement over straight scalar code though. If you don't want an explicit loop then you can just unroll this into 5 operations.